# How to use std::exception -- stack trace plus memory leak

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out the best way to deal with exceptions.

C++ says that any datatype can be thrown as an exception, but there is no way to tell what data type has been thrown, which makes exceptions essentially worthless.  However, I am assuming that these days everyone throw std::exception, so that is safe in a catch.  Is that a fair assumption?

(I am building a library that will be used by others, so has to fit in with other code that I do not control.)

The Exception.what function returns a char * (not a string) with no way to free it.  Of course, that string should contain information about the exception, for example if a file is not found then the name of the file that was not found.  I assume that we just tolerate a small memory leak here when exceptions are thrown.  Correct?

It is unclear how reliably stack traces can be generated in a general way and sent to a log file.  (In a production environment when things go wrong, not in a debugger.)  So I was thinking of inserting otherwise redundant try/catch blocks at interesting places in the code which can add logging  and append extra information to the what text and then rethrow a new exception.  But that process will, of course, destroy any stack trace.  For example

```
foo = stuff();
try {
  processStuff()
} catch (std::exception& ex) {
  string msg = "While processing " + foo.toString() + ": " + ex.what;
  log << msg;
  throw std::exception((char[])msg);
}
```

Is that the best approach?

There are lots of articles that describe the basic classes but nothing I could find on how to really make them work in practice.  Links appreciated.

(Here again I am trying to write Java/.Net in C++.  Is that a hopeless cause?)

Comment: @CyberSpock you are assuming that only one person/organization wrote all the code.  That is rarely the case in modern software.  So you cannot catch what you do not know about.  (And throw() is rarely used and a really bad idea anyway, along with Java "checked" exceptions.)

Comment: In my haste I think I misread your question, the best you can do since you are building a library, is to have your own clear defined strategy when it comes to your exceptions and let users of your library know that strategy.

Answer (score 4):

**Type of exception**
What type of exception object can be thrown is part of the function / method's public contract.

Often, libraries may introduce their own exception types which may or may not inherit from `std::exception`.

*Recommended:* throw std::exception or an exception inherited from it. Document the type(s) of exception thrown. Usually, you will have a "library default", such as

> *Unless stated otherwise, all methods and functions in this library may throw an exception of type `mylib::exception` or a type inherited from it.*

**char * what()**
The (implied?) assumption is that the pointer is valid as long as the exception object is valid. No necessity to free the string manually, no reason for leak.

If you need to store the text for later, make a copy of it - e.g. by assigning to `std::string`.

**Stack traces**
... are not part of the C++ standard. Furthermore, most compiler implementations allow generating code that does not allow re-discovering a stack trace. (the respective option usually says something about "stack frame").

However, for most compilers, libraries exist that can add this stack trace, but this usually requires access to the debug symbols.

**"Redundant" try/catch**
You might need them anyway.
The perfect exception must support different aspects:

- it contains instructions or hints for the end user how to remove a blocking issue (*"Cannot open file bibbit.txt because it is read only"*)
- it contains information for support and development why the error occurred, allowing them to possibly avoid it  / handle it better in the future. (Such as ... the stack trace)
- it needs to allow calling code to detect known exceptions and handle them specifically (e.g. *the file the user wants to open is read-only, ask user if they want to open in read-only mode, and try again*)

Rarely an exception does all that perfectly. But repackaging at certain "layers" helps a lot here - even though this makes us lose some of the beauty of exceptions.

Does that help?

---

Edit regarding your edit:

Generally ok, but **DO NOT** re-construct the exception. Change your code to:

```
 ...
 catch (std::exception& ex) {
  string msg = "While processing " + foo.toString() + ": " + ex.what;
  log << msg;
  throw;  // <--- !!!!!!
}
```

This re-throws the original exception, so catch handlers further down can still distinguish the different types:

```
  void Foo() {
     class random_exception : public std::exception { ... }
     try {
        ...
        if (rand() % 2) throw random_exception();
        ...
     }
     catch(std::exception const & x)
     {
        log << x.what();
        throw;
     }
   } 

   int main()
   {
      try {
        Foo();
      }
      catch(random_exception const & x)
      {
         cout << "A random exception occurred, you can try again";
      }
      catch(std::exception const & x)
      {
         cout << This didn't work. " << x.what(); 
      }
      catch(...) // catches all exception types, but you don't know what
      {
         cout << "Uh, oh, you are doomed.".
      }
   }
```

Of course, that's an issue when repackaging the exception.

---

Some things I'm leaning to:

The exception type to be thrown is a thin wrapper around a (smart) pointer. This allows storing exceptions (e.g. to pass them to another thread, or as an "inner exception" when repackaging) without losing type information:

I allow separate messages for end user and for diagnostics. End user message is required, diagnostics is usually generated from (and contains) the error code and context. User will see no "weird numbers and techie gibberish" unless they click on "details".

Instead of including parameters in the error message:

```
msg = "Could not open file bibbit.txt (tried 5 times)"; // :-(
```

I use a fixed message, and a list of (name, value) parameters.

```
msg = "Could not open file";  // :-)
msg.Add("filename", filename).Add("retries", retryCount);
```

This should simplify localization, and allows the caller to access individual attributes for known errors, allowing more specific handling.

Comment: What do you mean by "exception type to be thrown is a thin wrapper around a (smart) pointer. "  Some way of repackaging exceptions is what is missing (c.f. Java, .net).

Comment: I think that the main purpose of exceptions is your second, to fix bugs.  The top level catcher just logs, cleans up as best it can, and maybe retries or moves onto the next case, or reports to the user that something bad happened providing the exception text as techie details.  std::exception is not good enough for anything else.  So I take your point about re-constructing, but I think it is better to improve the message which for C++ means re-constructing.  "Could not read myfile.foo, status 123" is a much more useful diagnostic than "Error reading some file, satus 123".

Comment: re smart pointer: we can assign a `MyException`-derived object to a `MyException *`, but not to an `MyException` (without slicing). If we'd throw e.g. a `shared_ptr<MyException>`, repackaging would be easy to implement - but we'd lose inheritance from `std::exception`. That's why the thin wrapper. It certainly has downsides (or at least affects how exception handlers filter exceptions).

Comment: re purpose: Depends on the product and its users of course. For some products *"An error occurred, maybe you want to click another button."* is not enough. Users can fix many problems *given they have the right information*. However, many users - developers, even - just sto trying if that information is embedded in an error message. --- Point 3 allows dealing with known errors after the fact: test for known errors *before* you try is often preferrable, but you can't always do that.

Comment: For repackaging, I would have thought that it would just copy the exception object (and hopefully deeply or smartly), no?  For errors, users generally like as much info as possible to find out what is going on, possibly behind a "details..." button.  And thank you very much for taking the trouble to post your answer.

Comment: @aberglas: Problem is that you cannot deeply copy a derived object to a base class, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing. e.g. if I have a derived exception class with additional data and overridden virtual methods, I can't store that in the base class, and the modified behavior is lost. But a *pointer* to the base class can reference an instance of a derived class, though.

Answer (score 2):

> However, I am assuming that these days everyone throw std::Exception, so that is safe in a catch. Is that a fair assumption?

That's mostly a safe assumption. Some people insist in  throwing random stuff, but it's not your business - if you are a library you throw exceptions and at most you catch your own, you shouldn't be concerned with what other people throw (your code should use RAII anyway to avoid resource leaks - this covers even the case where e.g. callbacks throw stuff you don't know).

> The Exception.what function returns a char * (not a string) with no way to free it. Of course, that string should contain information about the exception, for example if a file is not found then the name of the file that was not found. I assume that we just tolerate a small memory leak here when exceptions are thrown. Correct?

Nope. The string returned by `what` normally does not result in a memory leak. Either is statically allocated (I've seen many simple exception classes that just return a string literal) or it's managed inside the exception itself (`std::runtime_error` normally contains an `std::string`, with `what` returning the result of its `c_str` method). In general, you can assume that whatever `what` results is there as long as the exception lives - if you need it outside the `catch` block copy it into an `std::string` or something.

This is actually *required* by the standard:

> The return value remains valid until the exception object from which it is obtained is destroyed or a non-const member function of the exception object is called.

(C++11, §18.8.1 ¶10)

> It is unclear how reliably stack traces can be generated in a general way and sent to a log file. (In a production environment when things go wrong, not in a debugger.) So I was thinking of inserting otherwise redundant try/catch blocks at interesting places in the code which can add logging and append extra information to the what text and then rethrow a new exception. But that process will, of course, destroy any stack trace.

Stack traces in C++ are a sad story; there's no portable way to generate them, you have to resort to platform-specific calls (or to libraries that abstract them); personally I used several approaches in the past:

- on a new, multi-platform Qt application I wrote my own "fat" exception class, which saved the stack trace (I derived from [`booster::exception`](http://cppcms.com/cppcms_ref/latest/classbooster_1_1exception.html), which already bundles the stack trace-saving part) and added the possibility to add extra information while the exception gets caught and rethrown, similar to how [Boost.Exception](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html) is implemented (important: Boost.Exception != booster::exception, they are completely unrelated); see [here](https://bitbucket.org/skynet_bm/exceptions/src/c4f155fde41fa3f4e42a5c43c15fb3291a2d55fb/exceptions.hpp?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default), it's full of Qt types but you can get the idea;
- on a legacy project which throw the most bizarre types (and there's no way to change them to a common exception type) I just hooked (via linker tricks) the throw and I always save the stack trace in a global circular buffer, which is printed out if an exception is not caught.

Your approach is flawed because not only it loses parts of the stack trace, but even the type information about the exception. Look up how Boost.Exception does its thing to see how to do it right. Also, you *never, ever* throw a `new` (=heap allocated) exception, otherwise freeing it becomes a burden to people who want to catch it (also, probably nobody will catch it because no one catches by pointer, you normally catch by reference).

Comment: How can booster::exception maintain type information?  Somebody throws a FooException, you convert it to a boost exception, type info completely gone.  No?  (If other people would use a decent exception class in the first place this problem would be gone.  But they do not.  They use, at best, std::exception.)  I had intended to wrap the exception Java style which at least keeps the original available.

Comment: For Exception.what, you are assuming that the catcher would never try to keep the pointer around beyond the lifetime of the exception object.  E.g. to return it from the catching method.  Having been burnt before with weird memory corruption bugs I always make pessimistic assumptions.  Maybe too pessimistic in this case.

Comment: @aberglas: you don't convert a thing, you just do std::throw_with_nested if you are wrapping an exception coming from someone else (if you actually want to do it).

Comment: @aberglas: if the catcher keeps around the pointer he's violating the contract of std::exception, so let him burn in fire.

Comment: I had not seen std::throw_with_nested, thanks, I will read more although it seems totally back to front at first glance.  When you say "violate the contract of what" I don't see how there is a contract, certainly not in the method signature -- C programmers traditionally just hope for the best.  And thank you very much for taking the trouble to write this detailed answer.

Comment: @aberglas: yep, `throw_with_nested` is a recent addition (C++11) and feels really like a kludge (the "rethrow the inner exception to unpack the nested exceptions" thing is ridicolous), although I can't see much better approaches that remain compatible with the semantic of C++98.

Comment: @aberglas: about "what": that's specified in the standard (§18.8.1 ¶10): *The return value remains valid until the exception object
from which it is obtained is destroyed or a non-const member function of the exception object is called.* This is also written on almost any C++ reference you can find around (cppreference.com, cplusplus.com, MSDN, libstd++ docs, all have this remark). And C programmers that "just hope for the best" typically don't go very far, the language isn't very forgiving...

Comment: BTW, [here](https://bitbucket.org/skynet_bm/exceptions/src/c4f155fde41fa3f4e42a5c43c15fb3291a2d55fb/exceptions.hpp?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)'s my implementation of the "first approach" described above, it uses mostly Qt data types but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `std::stack_trace` will be part of C++ 23.

Under GCC (yes, I know, not universal), you can use `std::current_exception` to get information about the current exception.  For instance, the following code will return the mangled name of the exception type:

```
std::string current_exception_type()
{
    std::string result;

    if (std::current_exception())
    {
        auto p = std::current_exception().__cxa_exception_type();
        if (p)
        {
            result = p->name();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

To demangle the name, you can use:

```
std::string demangle_cpp(char const* name)
{
    std::string result;
    char*   demangled(nullptr);

    try
    {
        int status;
        demangled = abi::__cxa_demangle(name, 0, 0, &status);
        if (demangled != nullptr) result = demangled;
    } catch(...)
    {
        
    }

    if (demangled != nullptr) free(demangled);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers cover how to use C++ exceptions. Here's how to do them with stack traces:

You can make a custom traced exception object that embeds a stack trace when thrown. This can be implemented with `std::stacktrace` or you could use a library like [cpptrace](https://github.com/jeremy-rifkin/cpptrace) which implements traced exceptions for C++11 and up. Then it's as simple as:

```cpp
throw cpptrace::runtime_error("demo");
```

The stack trace is included in the what() string and you can also access it in an exception handler:

```
try {
    ...
} catch(cpptrace::exception& e) {
    e.get_trace().print();
}
```